# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, .net, aforge

I am making a simple camera with a 3,2,1 countdown in C# using a Windows Form that opens a new Form to display the captured image. When the first Form is left running idle, it will eventually error out with: "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code".

The program appears to indicate the error is that pictureBox1.Image is being used elsewhere:

```
pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. Here is all of the code relating to the camera:

```
    private static object locker = new Object();
    private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevice;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalFrame;

    public Image File { get; private set; }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        if (CaptureDevice == null)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            }
        }
        foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
        {
            lock(locker)
            { 
            comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
        }
            }
        lock (locker)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
            button1.PerformClick();
            button2.BringToFront();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        lock (locker)
        {
            button1.SendToBack();
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
            FinalFrame.Start();
        }



    }

    private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            try
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); // <- Here is where the program indicates there is an error
            }
            catch (Exception exec)
            {
                Console.Write(exec);
           }
        }
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinalFrame.IsRunning == true)
       {
           FinalFrame.Stop();
      }
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.SendToBack();
        button2.Hide();
        customLabel1.Show();
        await Task.Delay(200);
        customLabel1.BringToFront();
        customLabel1.Refresh();
        await Task.Delay(800);
        customLabel1.Refresh();
        customLabel1.Text = "2";
        await Task.Delay(800);
        customLabel1.Refresh();
        customLabel1.Text = "1";
        await Task.Delay(800);
        customLabel1.Refresh();
        customLabel1.Text = "3";
        customLabel1.Hide();
        button2.Show();
        button2.BringToFront();

        button2.Text = "CAPTURE";
        Form2 myPic = new Form2();
        myPic.pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone() as Image;
        myPic.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Comment: Most video capture devices raise their "NewFrame" event on a worker thread.  That triggers a threading bug in your code, failure will be random.  The PictureBox.Image property is *not* thread-safe, you must use BeginInvoke() to ensure the assignment occurs on the UI thread.  Be sure to copy the image before you call BeginInvoke().  It is also a bit doubtful that Clone() is good enough, you may well need to make a deep copy with the Bitmap(Image) constructor.  And you must use Dispose() to get rid of bitmap objects that you no longer use.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I am a little confused however? Why would I copy the pictureBox1.Image before calling BeginInvoke()? The only thing I'm doing in NewFrame is copy the image, so would BeginInvoke() be applied to anything?

Comment: Not pictureBox1.Image, you have to copy eventArgs.Frame.  That bitmap is generally only valid while the event is raised.  Which is why you had to use Clone() in the first place.  When you use BeginInvoke(), the assignment occurs later, after the event handler stopped running.  You don't want to add another threading bug :)

Comment: I I believe this has solved my issue! The stream does seems to lag a little bit now, but I'm sure that's an issue with making the Form Fullscreen, as it runs up to speed when the Form size is reduced. Thank you very much for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

You must dispose all previously used images.

```
//if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
```

Comment: I appreciate your response! Unfortunately even when disposing Picturebox1.Image if not null, the program still eventually crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problem. Solution is to set `Image` in UI thread only.

So optimal method would look something like this:

```cs
void SetImageThreadSafe(PictureBox pb, Image img)
{
    if (pb.InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke((Action) delegate
        {
            SetImageThreadSafe(pb, img);
        });
        return;
    }

    pb.Image?.Dispose();
    pb.Image = img;
}
```